# Oracle Jet: Unable to make hybrid app with Ojet cli 9.1

Tags: oracle-jet

I am trying to build a hybrid app using ojet and ojet-cli. I am referring the getting started page on the official ojet site.

I can successfully scafold web app using the ojet-cli and serve it but when I type the command `ojet add hybrid` I get the below error

```
   {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE',
  message: '(during updateConfigXml) The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Document'
}
```

Below is the complete log from my console

```
~/Desktop/testApp                                                                                                               ⍉
▶ ojet add hybrid
? Please choose the platforms you want to install iOS
Adding platform: ios
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@^6.1.0


Adding ios project...


Creating Cordova project for the iOS platform:
    Path: platforms/ios

    Package: org.oraclejet.testapp
    Name: testApp

iOS project created with cordova-ios@6.1.0

Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist". Adding it to the project


Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios

Adding cordova-plugin-whitelist to package.json


Adding platform: browser
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-browser@^6.0.0


Adding browser project...

Creating Cordova project for cordova-browser:
    Path: /Users/hellonuh/Desktop/testApp/hybrid/platforms/browser

    Name: testApp

Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for browser

6.0.0

{
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE',
  message: '(during updateConfigXml) The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Document'
}
```

Below are my environment details

```
├── @oracle/ojet-cli@9.1.0
├── cordova@10.0.0
└── npm@6.14.8

▶ node -v
v14.5.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please drop your Node version down to the LTS release and try again.  We always see issues when people are using the "current" release of Node.

Answer (score 0):

Given that support for cordova-based hybrid apps is diminishing (to put it mildly), I advise against building one.
You are better-off investing in the PWA technology with JET.
You can create a normal webpp with PWA capability using jet cli e.g.

```
 ojet create myPWApp --template=navbar --pwa
```

Or add PWA to an existing JET WebApp e.g.

```
 ojet add pwa
```

with more capabilities being added to browsers, PWAs are suitable for most cases as installable apps with offline capabilities.
The main gap in PWA so far has been the support for Web Push Notification in iOS.
The good news is, that is coming to iOS in (2023) as Apple announced